# GTK non blocking pause

Tags: c, gtk

I have a gtk+-3.0 application written in C, currently (gcc) compiled and run under Windows 7 / msys64, that communicates with a bespoke device via a serial interface.

It needs to pause briefly (fraction of a second) between writing to the device and reading a reply from the device, to allow time for the device to return data, otherwise there's no data available in the serial input buffer.

The application works in a fashion if I use sleep(1), but is unresponsive to user events due to the repeated sleeps.

Using g_timeout_add or g_timeout_add_seconds doesn't appear to help, because the first call to the function occurs at the end of the first interval, by which time the serial read attempt has executed, finding no data.

Thanks in anticipation of your suggestions.

```
//   P O L L   C O N T R O L L E R   F O R   I T S   S E T T I N G S
    network->poll_event_source_id = gdk_threads_add_timeout(POLL_INTERVAL, zf_controller_poll, network);  // will use G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT

...

gint zf_controller_poll(gpointer data)  // thread to obtain controller settings at regular intervals
{
    gboolean res = FALSE;
    t_network *network;

    network = data;

    poll_iteration = (poll_iteration + 1);

    printf("zf_controller_poll iteration %d\n", poll_iteration);

    if (connection_running == FALSE)
    {
        printf("Not connected to controller\n");
        error_popup(network->main_window, "Not connected to controller!");
        return(0);
    }

    if (poll_running)  // only poll again after previous poll ended
    {
      printf("poll still running\n");
      return(1);
    }

    busy_state = TRUE;  // prepare to activate "busy..." timeout
    g_timeout_add_seconds(2, zf_progress_update, network);  // activate "busy..." timeout

    res = timer_read(network);  // ***
    if (res)
    {
      printf("obtained controller settings\n");
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Failed to obtain controller settings\n");
    }

    busy_state = FALSE;  // terminate "busy..." timeout

    return(1);  // if thread returns false (zero), timeout will be automatically destroyed and function won't be called again
}

...

gboolean timer_read (gpointer data)
{
    t_network *network;
    gint i, val, err;
    gdouble val_double;
    gchar text[10];

    network = data;
    i=0; val = 0; val_double = 0; err = 0;

    poll_running = TRUE;  // only poll again after previous poll ended, 

    for (i = 0; i<MAX_CHANNELS; i++)
    {

        if (gtk_switch_get_active(GTK_SWITCH(network->entry_toggle_mode[i])) == TRUE)
        {
            err = controller_send(get_channels[i], &val, network);  // ***

            if ((err == NO_CONNECTION) || (err == RECONNECTION_FAIL))
            {
                send_fail_action(network);
                network->tag_timer_read = 0; /*set tag to zero because time out will be destroyed here*/
                poll_running = FALSE;  // allow poll again after previous poll ended
                return(FALSE);
            }
            sprintf(text, "%d", val);
            gtk_entry_set_text (GTK_ENTRY(network->output_channel_array[i]), text);
            val = 0; err = 0;
        }else
            gtk_entry_set_text (GTK_ENTRY(network->output_channel_array[i]), "0");
    }

    poll_running = FALSE;  // only poll again after previous poll ended, 
    return(TRUE);
}

...

gint controller_send (const gchar *message, gint *valptr, gpointer main_data)
{
    gchar reply[2000] = {'\0'};
    unsigned char reply_s[4096];
    gint err = 0;
    gint val = 0;
    FILE *fileptr;
    t_network *network = main_data;
    int i, j;
    const char *message_s;
    char controller_cmd[25];

      j = strlen(message);
      if (j > 25)
        j = 25;
      for(i = 0; i < j; i++)
      {
        controller_cmd[i] = message[i];  // copy contents of wifi IP gchar buffer to intermediate buffer
      }
    message_s = controller_cmd;  // copy contents of intermediate buffer to serial char buffer

    time_t t = time (NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);

    if (connection_running == FALSE)
    {
        printf("Not connected to controller\n");
        fileptr = fopen("logfile.txt", "a");
        fprintf(fileptr, "%d.%d.%d %d:%d:%d\t Not connected to controller\n", tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_mon+1, tm.tm_year+1900, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
        fclose(fileptr);
        return(NO_CONNECTION);
    }

    /*send message to controller*/
    if(network->comm_serial)  //  send via serial port if connected
    {
      err = zf_serial_send(network->comport_num, message_s);  // ***
    }
    else                      //  send via wifi IP
    {
      err = func_socket_send(network->s, message);
    }
    printf("error value: %d\n", err);

    /*if message send fails then: */
    if(err != 0)
    {
      if(network->comm_ip)  //  try to re-establish TCP/IP session
      {
        network->connect_thread = g_thread_new("id_reconnect", func_reconnect_after_failPtr, network);  /*call connect function in separate thread to keep GUI responsive*/
        g_thread_unref (network->connect_thread);
      }
        connection_running = FALSE;
        fileptr = fopen("logfile.txt", "a");
        fprintf(fileptr, "%d.%d.%d %d:%d:%d\t Error occurred on send, socket closed, trying to reconnect \n", tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_mon+1, tm.tm_year+1900, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
        fclose(fileptr);
        /*print error value*/
        printf("error value %d\n", err);
        return (NO_CONNECTION);
    }

    err = 0;

    if(network->comm_serial)  //  receive via serial port if connected
    {
      err = zf_serial_recv(network->comport_num, reply_s);  // ***
      j = strlen(reply_s);
      if (j > 2000)
        j = 2000;  // don't write beyond length of destination buffer
      for(i = 0; i < j; i++)
      {
        reply[i] = reply_s[i];  // copy contents of serial char buffer to wifi IP gchar buffer
      }
    }
    else                      // receive via wifi IP
    {
      err = func_socket_receive(network->s, reply);
    }

    if (err != 0)
    {
        fileptr = fopen("logfile.txt", "a");
        fprintf(fileptr, "%d.%d.%d %d:%d:%d\t Error occurred on receive, socket closed, trying to reconnect \n", tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_mon+1, tm.tm_year+1900, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
        fclose(fileptr);
        connection_running = FALSE;
      if(network->comm_ip)  //  try to re-establish TCP/IP session
      {
        network->connect_thread = g_thread_new("id_reconnect", func_reconnect_after_failPtr, network);  /*call re connect function in separate thread to keep GUI responsive*/
        g_thread_unref(network->connect_thread);
      }
        /*print error value*/
        printf("error value %d\n", err);
        return (NO_CONNECTION);

    }else
    {
        val = get_extract_value(reply);
        *valptr = val;
    }

    return(0);
}

...

gint zf_serial_recv(int comport_num, unsigned char *reply)
{
    int recv_size = 0;

    recv_size = Serial_PollComport(comport_num, reply, 4095);

    reply[recv_size] = 0;  // terminate string with null

    if (recv_size <= 0)
    {
        printf("Serial reception failed: %d\n", recv_size);
        Serial_CloseComport(comport_num);
        return(1);
    }

    printf("\nreceived serial %dbytes\n", recv_size);
    printf("serial reply: %s\n", reply);

    return (0);
}

...

gint zf_serial_send(int comport_num, const char *message)
{
    gint bytes_send;
    gboolean res;

    bytes_send = Serial_SendBuf(comport_num, message, strlen(message));  // ***

    if( bytes_send < 0)
    {
        printf("Serial send failed: %d\n", bytes_send);
        Serial_CloseComport(comport_num);
        return (1);
    }

    printf("Serial send string: %s\n", message);

//  g_timeout_add_seconds(serial_wr_pause, zf_serial_wr_pause, (gpointer) bytes_send);
// next line does not delay - (first) execution will be in (approx) 1 second
//  res = g_timeout_add_seconds(1, zf_serial_wr_pause, (gpointer) bytes_send);

    sleep(1);  // allow time for controller response to arrive in serial read buffer

    return(0);
}

...

int Serial_PollComport(int comport_number, unsigned char *buf, int size)
{
  int n;

  ReadFile(Cport[comport_number], buf, size, (LPDWORD)((void *)&n), NULL);

  return(n);
}

...

int Serial_SendBuf(int comport_number, unsigned char *buf, int size)
{
  int n;

  if(WriteFile(Cport[comport_number], buf, size, (LPDWORD)((void *)&n), NULL))
  {
    return(n);
  }

  return(-1);
}
//...
// snippet of serial port initialisation:
//...
  COMMTIMEOUTS Cptimeouts;

/* A value of MAXDWORD, combined with zero values for both the ReadTotalTimeoutConstant and ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier members, specifies that the read operation is to return immediately with the bytes that have already been received, even if no bytes have been received. */
  Cptimeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout         = MAXDWORD;
  Cptimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier  = 0;
  Cptimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant    = 0;
  Cptimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
  Cptimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant   = 0;

  if(!SetCommTimeouts(Cport[comport_number], &Cptimeouts))
  {
    printf("unable to set comport time-out settings\n");
    CloseHandle(Cport[comport_number]);
    return(1);
  }
```

Comment: Don't rely on wait-times to get something working. There are better approaches to that.

Comment: Can you post snippets of code that demonstrate how your app works (sync or async), how the device is initialized, and your read logic?

Comment: You're in a mono-threaded application, so using sleep stops the whole thread, leaving GTK no chance to handle and refresh the UI.
Please add some code to show how and when you're trying to wirte/read the data and how you're creating the timeout callbacks, and what you do in them.

Comment: The polling of the controller on the serial port is done in a separate thread.

Comment: Herewith some code, the relevant calls highlighted with // ***

Comment: New to posting on stackoverflow - only allows 600 characters here